# Getting micrometer metrics from a jar to a spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, micrometer

I have a spring boot application in which I use the jar.
In that jar, I have integrated micrometre timers to measure some code flows,
now I want those metrics to be sent to data dog.
Is there a way to do that?
when I ran my spring boot (2.4.4) application and hit the endpoint localhost:/actuator/metrics, I got

```java
{"names":[]}
```

which means the spring boot application cannot pick up the timers.
Can anyone please help me with this

P.S I have added this config too.

```yaml
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
  metrics:
    enable:
      all: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your metrics endpoint is empty but it should not be out of the box.
This means that you did something that broke it.
If you are creating a MeterRegistry manually or use the global, try to inject the registry that Boot creates into your components instead.